# Exclude route from netsh interface

Tags: windows-10, vpn, powershell, routing, netsh

My setup is as follows:

- Windows 10, Corona forced home office, I'm an external contractor at a huge company
- I'm connecting to the VPN of my company, called `MyVPN`, some internal IPs of our client are accessible for us via this VPN
- I set up split tunneling with `Set-VpnConnection "MyVPN" -SplitTunneling 1`
- All the internal IPs I need to call with the VPN start are in the same IP range `999.0.0.0/8` (example IP range, thousands of different IPs beong to this company)
- So I added all these IPs via `netsh interface ipv4 add route 999.0.0.0/8  "MyVPN"`
- This works, I can call internal IPs via the VPN while all other calls don't go through my VPN
- My issue is now:

  - I can't access all internal IPs via VPN, because of missing Firewall routes (I have to request  them which takes some time and a lot of discussions... So I want to avoid this)
  - But some of these internal IPs can be accessed globally **without** the VPN
  - So I now have the issue, that I can't access these IPs through my VPN, but I could access them if I turn my VPN off. But my netsh route routes them all to the VPN, which leads to a timeout
- I was thinking to somehow exclude these IPs from the netsh route, but I don't know how. Is there a way?

  - Like `netsh interface ipv4 exclude route 999.40.60.80  "MyVPN"`
  - The IPs I have an issue with are scattered throughout their whole range, no pattern or similarities

That's the output of `netsh interface ipv4 show route` (German :) "WLAN" is German for "WiFi")
[image]

---

I found it! Based on user1686's answer I tried some stuff and that's the solution

```
netsh interface ipv4 add route 999.40.60.80/32 "WLAN" 192.168.178.1
```

with `WLAN` beeing the name of my WiFi interface and `192.168.178.1` beeing my default gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add normal routes through your regular Internet gateway:

```
netsh interface ipv4 add route 999.40.60.80/32 "WLAN" 192.168.178.1
```

Copy the 'gateway' value from your current 0.0.0.0/0 route.

Comment: Thanks, but this results in "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect", even if I enclose 192.168.178.1 with paranthesis (and I also added /32 to the company IP. So this was tried `netsh interface ipv4 add route 999.40.60.80/32 "192.168.178.1"`
When I write "WLAN" instead of "192.168.178.1" it gets sorted below the VPN entry, and so the VPN route "grabs" it

Comment: Routes are not sorted "above" or "below". They're sorted by prefix length – a longer prefix (e.g. /32) always wins over a shorter prefix (e.g. /8 or /0).

Comment: Thanks, I found it! I had to add my WiFi interface name between the two IPs, see the extension of my question.